# How to include .jar library, that is inside java project and make application use this library that is inside application after compilation?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

I know this question is probably very easy for you, but I have real problems with it.

When I put, for example, apache commons-lang jar library into project's folder lib that is on the same level as src folder and add this jar library into project's build patch, eclipse compiles everything without errors and it puts all sources into exported .jar file (including lib folder and the contents).

BUT, when I start application, I am getting this error:

`23:55:42 [SEVERE] Exception in thread "main" 
23:55:42 [SEVERE] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`

Can someone explain me why JVM does not see libraries that I have in lib folder and that are defined in project's build patch?

What I have to do to make my compiled application see this jar files?

Comment: When you launch your application jar using the [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command, you can specify the runtime classpath using `-cp` option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is it possible to make application use jars in lib folder automaticaly or I have to create simple launcher that will execute java -cp with libraries locations?

Comment: No. But, to avoid typing the command-line every time, you can create a shell/bat script to launch your application.

Comment: Did you check the other tab in your build path called 'Order and Export'? The lib must be selected if you want to include it within your .jar

Comment: jar files need to be listed explicitly in the -cp, unlike class files that can be added by just including the folder they are located [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html)

Comment: If I will create maven project instead of normal java project and I will add this apache common library to maven setup, will it fix this error?

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung I did not know about something like this. If I will check this .jar in this tab, will my jar application use jar files from lib folder that is inside exported application?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the classpath explicitly in the startup script unless you are using any container like tomcat, where you can place the libraries and dependencies in the lib folder.

You can use `-cp` and provide the path the library, so that the java program will use all the libraries which are required from the classpath mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Eby J

Comment: If I will create maven project instead of normal java project and I will add this apache common library to maven setup, will it fix this error?

Comment: Yes you can create a maven project and compile with all dependencies. maven goal to do this is . `mvn clean compile assembly:single`

Comment: I found something in eclipse called "Order and Export" in Build Path of my application's java project. If I will check apache library in this tab, will it find common apache lib if it will be inside compiled jar of my application?